# Why can't others update my newly created file?

Tags: svn

I creates a new file and committed, but when others update they can not find this file that I just created. What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you did (i.e. copy+paste the command line and results - both for the `svn add` and the `svn commit`).  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Are you sure that their working copies should get this change after running `svn update`? What URL did you commit to and what is the root URL of their working copies? Find this out by running `svn info` at the root of your working copy.